# Is it possible to bind the second parameter of a lambda function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm new to C++11 lambdas and would like to turn a binary lambda into a unary one by binding its second parameter:

```
auto lambda1 = [] (int a, int b) { return a+b; };
auto lambda2 = std::bind2nd(lambda1, 5);
```

Compilation fails with

```
error: no type named 'first_argument_type' in 'struct main(int, char**)::<lambda(int, int)>'
     class binder2nd
```

[How] can this be done?

Comment: `auto lambda2 = [lambda1](int a) { return lambda1(a, 5); }` Just forget `bind`, lambdas are easier to use and more readable.

Comment: `bind2nd` & `bind1st` are `deprecated` & hence replaced with `bind`

Comment: @AnkitAcharya In C++17 maybe, but as of now they are still valid. This is of rather theoretical interest anyway.

Comment: @oarfish They *are* deprecated. They've been deprecated since c++11. In C++17 they're planned to be removed entirely.

Comment: Yes, so? Deprecation ≠ Invalidity. I don't intend to use deprecated features, but saying they are *replaced* by `bind` is not correct before C++17. It's just a semantics issue and irrelevant to the question.

Comment: [lib.function.objects]p5 (in some C++03 draft): *"To enable adaptors and other components to manipulate function objects that take one or two arguments it is required
that the function objects correspondingly provide typedefs `argument_type` and `result_type` for function objects that
take one argument and `first_argument_type`, `second_argument_type`, and `result_type` for function objects that take two arguments."* That's why it won't work for lambdas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   auto lambda1 = [](int a, int b) { return a+b; };
   auto lambda2 = std::bind(lambda1, std::placeholders::_1, 5);
   //           ~~~~~~~^^^^~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^~~~
   return 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a3376427651e1ec)**

Also prefer to use `std::bind` over `std::bind1st` and `std::bind2nd` [since both were deprecated in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) and are scheduled to be removed in C++17.

Comment: This binds the first parameter, instead of the second. While wrapping another lambda as suggested by Columbo is preferable, I'm still curious whether it's possible.

Comment: @oarfish The code as is binds the second parameter to `5`.

Comment: Whoops, yes, the test I did was faulty.

Comment: I accept this answer since it's closest to what I had in mind despite not being the best way to go maybe.

Answer (score 16):

If you already employ lambda expressions, just use another one:

```
auto lambda2 = [&] (int i) {return lambda1(i, 5);};
```

Comment: I actually had not thought of that. Silly.

Comment: Could you explain, *why* `std::bind2nd` is not appropriate?

Comment: @user2079303 Because it's deprecated, illegible and not flexible in any way whatsoever?

Comment: @Columbo those are good reasons not to use it, but none of them does explains why it does not compile.

Comment: @user2079303 "appropriate" and "well-formed" are two different things ;-) The code is ill-formed because `bind2nd` expects the function object type to [provide some typedefs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binder12).